# Magento can not detect if customer is logged in or not

Tags: php, magento, session, singleton, magento-1.7

This is my php file which I am calling using ajax function call. For test purpose I also tried it calling directly.

```
include "/srv/www/htdocs/magento/app/Mage.php";

Mage::init();

if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn())
{
    echo 'Logged In';
}
else
{
    echo 'Not Logged In';
}
```

The code do not give any errors. I checked in apache error log. 
The magento 1.6.1 version I am using failes to check if user is logged in or not.
I tried to execute this code while the user is logged in and also when the user is NOT logged in.
But this code output only the else statement that is "Nog logged in"
Help please

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do check if this helps!

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';


umask(0);

Mage::app('default');

Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));

$sessionCustomer = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");

if($sessionCustomer->isLoggedIn()) {
  echo "Logged";
} else {
   echo "Not Logged";
}
```

for more details check here [Magento Customer login](http://huztechbuzz.wordpress.com/2014/06/20/magento-detect-if-customer-is-logged-in-or-not/)

Comment: Changing to double inverted comma do not help.

Comment: Not double inverted use Mage::app(); instead.

Comment: Oh sorry. My bad. I tried with require_once and Mage::app(); and it still do not work. It even do not give any error? AM I missing something in magento configuration?

Comment: that code works now. but it do not print the user / customer name.

Comment: To get the customer name i used the code from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028321/magento-how-do-i-echo-username

Comment: It works with me if I put `login.php` file inside the **magento root directory**. And the same code doesn't work outside it!

Comment: you need to change the path tom Mage file, check if that is a point  you have missed.

Comment: Can anyone help to convert the above code in context of magento 2 ?

Answer (score 7):

You may try this:

```
<?php if ($this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()): ?>
```